# Get the correct Value from HiddenField in ASP.NET Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, hidden-field

after i look around and tried a couple of solution i decided to post.Bear in mind that i am learning asp atm ( so my experience is little )

So the issue is the following:

I have an asp.net repeater pulling data from a database.
I have a `HiddenField` where i store an `ID`.

In the code behind i try to get that `ID` to a string but everything i tried it only returns me  a single ID which is 1.

Asp code :

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="dataRepeater" EnableTheming="true">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:HiddenField ID="prodID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("ProductID")%>' />

        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="addToCart" Text="Add to cart" OnClick="Something" />

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

C# code behind:

```cs
dataRepeater.DataSource = dt;
dataRepeater.DataBind();

protected void Something(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 string pID = "";

 for (int i = 0; i < dataRepeater.Items.Count; i++) {
  var item = dataRepeater.Items[i];

  var hf = item.FindControl("prodID") as HiddenField;
  pID = hf.Value;
 }
}
```

As i tried the foreach alternative, the result in `pID` is the same 1, where it should be the `product ID` from the database.

I am sure i did something wrong, but i can't figure it out what. 
Thx for your time.

Comment: When you look at the HTML source of the page, do you see different values for the hidden field in each repeater item?

Comment: Also, as per your code, on completion of for loop, pID would be holding the value of hidden field in the LAST repeater item. Does the last item in repeater has prodID hidden field value 1?

Comment: Yes i got different values. The answer to my problem is bellow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In button click `Something` method, there is no need to use `for` loop as it always returns the last iteration value. So use below code in your `OnClick` event to get clicked value:

```
//Get value from each button pressed in the RepeaterItem
var repeaterItem = ((Control)sender).NamingContainer;
string pID = (repeaterItem.FindControl("prodID") as HiddenField).Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but in case if anyone is looking for an answer.

You can use `CommandArgument` as the following:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="addToCart" Text="Add to cart" OnClick="Something" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ProductID")%>' />
```

Then, you can do this in "Something":

```
string ProductID = (sender as Button).CommandArgument;
```